# Favicon showing for the non-www URL but not for the www version

Tags: html, web

I'm trying to add a favicon to a website. I put it in the main folder of the site under the name favicon.ico. If I type the sitename *without* the www part then the favicon shows properly but it does not appear when I use the same URL but with the www prefixed.

I also tried the link tag but it did not help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: give your test link or add code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply waiting solved my problem. When I visited the page today, the favicon appeared properly for both versions (*without* the  tag added in the HTML). I still don't know the source of the issue but it seems to be over for now.

Thanks for all the answers anyway!

BTW I don't know how to close a topic in this case... :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pointing to the favicon file directly?

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
```

https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this one and it did not help. :( But I'm gonna give it another try.

Comment: try a ctrl+f5, or incognito mode. and please if you can share your link so i can have a look, it would be great.